# Double theme frame on DialogFragment with TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a TimePickerDialog using a DialogFragment as the [Android docs shows](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePickerFragment). However, when trying to apply the holo theme I'm getting a double framed effect when doing the following:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, this, hourOfDay, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
```

How can I apply the holo theme without having this issue?

[image]

Comment: same problem.. found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue and I solved it. Instead of use the constructor you propose, I used a ContextThemeWrapper like follows:

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
return new TimePickerDialog(wrapper, getActivity(), hour, minute,DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()))
```

It works for me :)

Comment: I can confirm this work. @Jona Accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem... Class `TimePickerDialog` inherits its own theme constants from `AlertDialog`. You must use those in order to get predictable results. Try this code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it.
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK,
        this, hourOfDay, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
```

Or maybe use `TimePickerDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`, if you prefer to stay with what user expects.

Constants you may use are:

- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`
- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT`
- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK`
- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`
- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL`